Unable to click on the UI elements on ios app screen developed using UI kit in Appium with java
I am facing some issues related to click on some of the elements in my ios app. The issue is happening only in one screen developed using uikit. I already tried following alternatives but nothing worked out .

upgrading/downgrading of appium server and client dependencies
use more wait to check if the issue is related to wait.
added some desired capabilities like newCommandTimeout.
updating XCUITestderiver and xcode .

Environment Details- Appium server 2.12.1, appium-java-client- 9.3.0 , xcuitestdriver version- 7.31.0 , xcode- 16.1 , java - 11
I am executing the tests on real device - iphone 11 with ios 17.6.1
